# angular js error Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs

**please solve the error, im very beginner in angular js.
i have struck at tutorial ca't go forward before clearing this error
thanks**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="mylanguageap">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-controller="languages">
  Select your favorite language:
    <button ng-click="php()">PHP</button>   
    <button ng-click="java()">JAVA</button>     
    <button ng-click="cpp()">C++</button>   
    <button ng-click="javascript()">JAVA SCRIPT</button>    
    <p>You have selected: {{ myfavlanguage  }}</p>
  </div>

  <script>
    var application = angular.module('mylanguageapp',[]);
    application.controller('languages', function($scope){
    $scope.myfavlanguage = 'None';
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is some problem in attaching modules that is why the error is there.

Comment: There is a typo in module name change ng-app="mylanguageap" to ng-app="mylanguageapp"

Answer (score 0):

Typo:

```
<html ng-app="mylanguageap">
```

vs

```
var application = angular.module('mylanguageapp',[]);
```